# Webhook Authenticity from Node.js to PHP

Tags: php, node.js, base64, webhooks, hmac

I need help translating this `Node.js` code into `PHP`. It's basically for authenticating whether the signature on my header is the same as the signature that has been encoded using `base64` and `HMAC-SHA256`.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const timestamp = "1570350275357";
const msg = {'key1':'world','key2':'world'};
const secretKey = "mysecretsecret";

const decodedKey = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'base64').toString('utf8');
const signature = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', decodedKey).update(timestamp + '.' + msg).digest('base64');

const signatureHeader = "+DCfT1wIMUiaZnlZB4u59/d5wkXKA89lv67Ov66vnyc=";

assert(signature === signatureHeader);
```

So I have my request body which is `{'key1':'world','key2':'world'}` , the timestamp `(x-duda-signature-timestamp` header) is `1570350275357` and a secret key which is `mysecretsecret`.

It also calculates for my signature `base64(hmac-sha256(secret-key, timestamp + "." + message))` which results in `+DCfT1wIMUiaZnlZB4u59/d5wkXKA89lv67Ov66vnyc=` , which is also the value to be found on this `x-duda-signature header` of the request.

I've already tried putting the pieces together on PHP and it just won't return a signature that is similar to my signature header which is `+DCfT1wIMUiaZnlZB4u59/d5wkXKA89lv67Ov66vnyc=`.

````
$getHeaders = apache_request_headers();

$timestamp = "1570350275357";

$signatureHeader = "+DCfT1wIMUiaZnlZB4u59/d5wkXKA89lv67Ov66vnyc=";

$secretKey = "mysecretsecret";

//Request Body
$message = '{'key1':'world','key2':'world'}';

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$timestamp.".".$message,$secretKey));

print_r($signature); // the value should be equal to ```$signatureHeader```
````

Any idea on where I went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you describe the values in the text? You should modify your code examples so that both are executable, i.e. already contain the concrete values for message, timestamp, (test!) key etc., see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This makes a repro easier and avoids divergent code.

Comment: Furthermore `const decodedKey = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'base64').toString('utf8')` only allows values for `secretKey` which are UTF8 decodable after base64 decoding. Otherwise the data will be corrupted, which is probably also not reproducible on PHP side. `mysecretsecret` in any case does not meet these requirements, e.g. `bXlzZWNyZXRzZWNyZXQ=` does.

Comment: @Topaco thank you so much for your detailed input, this helps a lot. I also think that the mysecretsecret is not supposed to be a normal string. I should contact their admin tech to clarify their webhook secretkey authentication.